# Why same postgres query is not working for double digit number?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jsonb

I am using postgres database for my application.

I have below data

```
    create table contacts (
        id int,
        contact_data jsonb
    );
    
    insert into contacts values
    (1,   '{
        "tags": [
            "MOCK_DATA (4)"
        ],
        "Email": "nk3ynman5@marriott.com",
        "reach": false,
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Interest": [
            "Dance"
        ],
        "Last Name": "Kynman",
        "First Name": "Nicko"
    }'),
    (2,   '{
        "ltv": "6",
        "City": "Bengaluru",
        "Email": "aaa@aa.com",
        "State": "Karnataka",
        "Country": "India",
        "latitude": 12.9715987,
        "Last Name": "World",
        "longitude": 77.5945627,
        "First Name": "Helo"
    }'),
    (3,   '{
        "ltv": "11",
        "Email": "sf3ortye8@ebay.co.uk",
        "reach": false,
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Country": "United States",
        "latitude": "37.09024",
        "Last Name": "Fortye",
        "longitude": "-95.712891",
        "First Name": "Sissie"
    }');
```

```
    Select * from contacts;
    
    +====+==================================================================================================================================+
    | id | contact_data                                                                                                                     |
    +====+==================================================================================================================================+
    | 1  | {"tags": ["MOCK_DATA (4)"], "Email": "nk3ynman5@marriott.com", "reach": false, "Gender": "Male", "Interest": ["Dance"], "Last... |
    +----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 2  | {"ltv": "6", "City": "Bengaluru", "Email": "aaa@aa.com", "State": "Karnataka", "Country": "India", "latitude": 12.9715987, "L... |
    +----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 3  | {"ltv": "11", "Email": "sf3ortye8@ebay.co.uk", "reach": false, "Gender": "Female", "Country": "United States", "latitude": "3... |
    +----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to fetch id who has ltv between 2 to 9. and it's giving 1 record. which is correct

```
    SELECT id from contacts where ( contact_data->> 'ltv' > '2' and contact_data->> 'ltv' < '9' );
    +====+
    | id |
    +====+
    | 2  |
    +----+
```

**Issue:**

Now i am trying between 2 to 12, which should give 2 records, but it's giving 0 data.

```
SELECT id from contacts where ( contact_data->> 'ltv' > '2' and contact_data->> 'ltv' < '12' );
```

Can anyone tell me what's the issue here. why I am not getting the value? here is [sql-fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=131162155bcbbb2e0f999fe2976d0e55&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL `->>` operator will return a `text` value. So you have too cast it in respective type.

Try below query:

```
SELECT id 
from contacts 
where ( 
    (contact_data->> 'ltv')::int > 3 and 
    (contact_data->> 'ltv')::int < 12 
);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e7449fdc6b8e6bf7197635f1aefcd7cc)
Only thing you have to take care is, `itv` must contain integer value only, otherwise casting will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the data type of `ltv`. They are strings and not numbers, so it is ordered lexicographically.

Cast it in the query to give it the meaning you want it to have.

EDIT: remove using number in the JSON, as retrieving a number field form JSON seems to not give a numeric value.

Comment: i tried with number but still it's not showing any data

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Try the casting after the JSON access, as this table might say you get always ```text``` if you retrieve something from a JSON: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE

Comment: So at the time of insertion I inserted LTV as number. and tried below query
`SELECT id from contacts where ( contact_data->> 'ltv' > 2 and contact_data->> 'ltv' < 12 );`

Comment: this will also now work. You should try like this `SELECT id from contacts where ( (contact_data->> 'ltv')::int > 3 and (contact_data->> 'ltv')::int < 12 );` . No matter you are providing value `6` or `"6"`. Only thing never store a non interger value in `ltv`